# Static properties / ViewModel (C#, WinRT)

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, windows-runtime

I have a static `UserAccount` class in my WinRT project. This class contains various static properties about the currently logged in user (like Username, e-mail address, ...). I need this info to be available from any view using binding (example - I want to display a personalized message `"Welcome, {0}"` - passing in the username - on one page in the app), but I need to be sure, that these conditions are satisfied:

1. Implement it in a correct MVVM pattern way
2. When user switches to another account when the app is running thru the Settings charms, the bound fields (like the message and so on) should automatically update with the new data.

I thought that it would be possible to create something like a global `UserAccountViewModel`, that would be a classic view model with the required properties, and which would be manually updated from the static `UserAccount` class, but that doesn't seem to be a nicest solution possible.

Can you think about a better way to accomplish this and satisfying both conditions listed above?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Similar situation occured with yet another class I need - NetworkStatus - which has IsInternetAvailable to know whether or not the app is connected, but I need to use this boolean to bind to IsEnabled property of different buttons in the app.

Comment: is {x:Static namespace:Class.Property} available for Windows RT XAML? If not one way to do it is to use a dependency injection container and register your user account information as a single instance type. Therefore, your ViewModel can get the UserAccount injected into the constructor. Are you using DI ?

Comment: I think the x:Static is not available. I thought about the DI approach to, but that made caused a little unfriendly access to the properties of UserAccount class from the code-behind (example - one of the properties is AccessToken, which I use to load data from a web service - now I would have to do something like ViewModelLocator.UserAccount.AccessToken (a little more messy code essentially)) or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you need to access view model properties from code behind? That's something that belongs inside the view model.

Comment: Sorry, I meant something else. Not code behind, but data access code which needs the AccessToken to load user data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sCreate a Base ViewModel that all other ViewModels inherit from.  You don't have to make it static now for all-access, as every ViewModel will already have access to it.  In the Binding, you don't specify *base.Property* either.

An abstract view model to contain properties *and* the functionality to populate this data.

```
public abstract class UserAccountViewModel : ObservableObject, IViewModel
{
    //use private member and do a RaisePropertyChanged("Username")
    public string Username { get; set; }

    private void GetUserInformation()
    {
        Username = BusinessLogic.GetUsername();
    }
}
```

Now you make your ViewModels inherit it

```
public class OtherViewModel : UserAccountViewModel { }
```

And you can bind directly to the parent property in **OtherView.xaml:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Username, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

BusinessLogic class has static GetUsername() method which retrieves the username.  To not repeat workload, retrieve only once but provide many.  So you'd be storing it static in your businesslogic until a Refresh concept it called.

**Alternatively**, you can have one ViewModel which gathers the data you want, then user EventAggregator or whatever you want to pass this around to all other ViewModels that need it.  This would remove the static businesslogic idea.  Using Prism's EventAggregator is great, ViewModels subscribe and one (or many) publish the event and includes the object/data to go with it.  So these other ViewModels could subscribe and receive immediately, or you could do two-way communication and have ViewModels 'Request' and then get the 'Response'. Not sure if you can utilize it, or have to roll your own, but the concept is valid and could be done with events passing a UserInfo object at least.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to mark your answer, I accidentaly forgot to do it ;-) .